# Teradata JDBC Error 1338 after certain number of batch executions

Tags: java, r, jdbc, batch-insert, rjdbc

I am trying to insert 3.8M records into a Teradata table containing 14 columns, through a batch of 10000 records using `RJDBC` package of R.
It always crashes after inserting 380000 records i.e. at 39th batch execution.
This is the error I get,

> Error in .jcall(ps, "[I", "executeBatch") :
>   java.sql.BatchUpdateException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC
>   15.10.00.22] [Error 1338] [SQLState HY000] A failure occurred while executing a PreparedStatement batch request. Details of the failure
>   can be found in the exception chain that is accessible with
>   getNextException.

I've tried changing to a different set of rows from the same dataframe. And, behavior remains same, crashes at the 39th batch execution.

Any idea what is this `Error 1338` and what could be the fix?
Also, it mentions about `getNextException` but how do I use that with R?

The approach I'm using is similar to this one
https://developer.teradata.com/blog/ulrich/2013/11/a-wider-test-case-on-r-jdbc-fastload

Comment: "Details of the failure can be found in the exception chain that is accessible with getNextException." -- So what does it say?

Comment: Thanks @StephenC for pointing that out. I should've put this in my original question. I am not sure of how to use `getNextException` with the approach I am using in R.

Answer (score 0):

To get the initial exception "object", you need to use .jgetEx to and then you can use the getNextException method on it to retrieve the root cause.

See [this link](https://developer.teradata.com/blog/amarek/2013/12/how-to-capture-chained-jdbc-fastload-sqlexceptionsqlwarning-messages-and-stack) on the teradata developers forum for a complete example.

Typical causes of an exception during a batch insert are:

- "value related": invalid values, excessive precision of numeric data
- "size related" : the inserted rows create a "no more room in database" error

Since you say that you've tested different datasets and they all fail at the same execution, that's very likely a "**no more room in database**".

However, this doesn't necessarily mean that the space that has been granted to you is full: it might be that the table has a poorly chosen *Primary Index* (or the data has an error that produces duplicate *primary index*), resulting in a very skewed distribution. In this case, you would be wasting a lot of space that could be reclaimed if you can define a more apt *primary index* (or use a NOPI table, if you're using it as some sort of a stage table).

[Here](http://community.teradata.com/t5/Database/Space-in-the-database/td-p/38564) you can find a discussion on this "space waste" topic with lots of useful queries to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Same happens to me I was trying to insert 27.4M records into a Teradata table containing 8 columns. I've got the same error at 5.35M row.

The only thing that works for me was **make a commit every 1M records.**

Answer (score 0):

So few notes here.

1. The first is GC. It's not an issue in the usual java program but under a load of millions records try to do eventually `Thread.sleep` with single seconds. This will trigger GC. I found some race conditions in the Teradata JDBC driver ver `17.00.00.03`. For performance purpose it is reusing old objects with a weak reference to something to be collected. When working with fastload™ or multiload™ loads, this became crucial.
2. Ensure you have enough space in your database. This also causes this exception.